# why this setInterval does not work inside for loop?

Tags: javascript

```
function countDown(){
    var count = ""
for(var i = 10; i > 0; i--){

    count = i;

    setInterval(function(){show(count)}, 1000);

      // i've try : setInterval(show(count), 1000);
    }   
}


function show(count){
        document.getElementById('tes').innerHTML = count;
    }
```

don't flag as duplicate, this is different thing!!
This is just experiment,

Comment: basically change your function to "function(count){show(count)}(count)"

Comment: or remove your count var and change it to "function(count){show(count)}(i)"

Comment: i'm sorry but can you give detail explaination? your code is looks syntacly incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The code should be

```
function countDown(){
    var count = "";
for(var i = 10; i > 0; i--){

    count = i;

    setInterval(show(count), 1000); //call function, do not create one here

      // i've try : setInterval(show(count), 1000);
    }   
}


function show(count){
        document.getElementById('tes').innerHTML = count;
    }

countDown(); //invokation
```